# Prove $f(tx)=|t|f(x)\implies(\exists\alpha>0)f(x)\geqslant\alpha\|x\|$

Tags: metric-spaces

Suppose that $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}^m=\{(x_1, ..., x_m)|x_i\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is the real vector space of $m$-tuples of real numbers. Let $\|\cdot\|:\mathbb{R}^m \to [0, \infty)$ be a norm on $\mathbb{R}^m$.

A function $f:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ is called absolutely homogeneous if $f(tx)=|t|f(x)$ for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Let $f:(\mathbb{R}^m, \|\cdot\|) \to (\mathbb{R}, |\cdot|)$ be a continuous function with $f(x)>0$ for every non-zero $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Show that if $f$ is absolutely homogeneous then there exists a positive constant $\alpha >0$ such that $\alpha \|x \| \leq f(x)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: 1) Use a descriptive title 2) What have you tried?/Where are you stuck?/What is your question? Consider editting your question to reflect these 2 points so as to avoid getting downvoted

Comment: I've just started learning this area, so don't really know how to solve this question, like what theorem or definitions should I use here.

Comment: Hints : Why is this function "determined" by the set $\{\|x\| = 1\}$? Why is that set compact? So $f$ attains a minimum and maximum on that set. Can you conclude now?

Comment: I've proved that the set $\{ x \in R^m: |x|=1\}$ is compact in $(R^m, | \cdot |)$. Moreover, I know that I need to use the extreme value theorem here, but I don't know how exactly to apply it. Could you please give me a more detailed explanation. Thank you!